# Horario abierto o cerrado usando JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un script en js el cual uso para colocar abierto o cerrado en una tienda, el código funciona bien, por ejemplo en el código que mostrare a continuación , la tienda abre a las 8am y cierra a las 10 pm, sin embargo ahora me veo en la necesidad de colocar en la tienda que aparezca cerrado los Domingos.
En el código trae uno comentario donde indica como hacerlo , sin embargo debido a mi falta de conocimiento en programación no he logrado hacerlo funcionar. agradecería si alguien me pudiera ayudar con esto.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    "use strict";
    var Now = new Date();
    var CurrentDay = Now.getDay();
    // opening time - 24 hours so 9:30am is 9, 30
    var OpeningTime = new Date(Now.getFullYear(), Now.getMonth(), Now.getDate(), 8);
    // closing time - 24 hours so 5:30pm is 17, 30
    var ClosingTime = new Date(Now.getFullYear(), Now.getMonth(), Now.getDate(), 22);
    var Open = (Now.getTime() > OpeningTime.getTime() && Now.getTime() < ClosingTime.getTime());
    days 0.sun 1.mon 2.tues 3.wed 4.thur 5.fri 6.sat 
    // CurrentDay !== 0 && the # is the day to exclude, so if I want to be closed on Sat6, Sun0, Wed3
    // CurrentDay !== 6 && CurrentDay !== 0 && CurrentDay !== 3 && Open
    if (CurrentDay !== 1 && CurrentDay !== 5 && Open) {
        $('.openstatus').toggle();

    } else if (CurrentDay !== 6 && Open) {
        $('.openstatus').toggle();

    }
});
```

El html es el siguiente

```
<div class="abierto-o-cerrado"> <span style="display: none;">Abierto Ahora</span> <span style="">Cerrado Ahora</span> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes corregir tus condicionales:

```
if (CurrentDay >= 1 && CurrentDay <= 6 && Open) {
    // Aqui tu codigo para mostrar que esta abierto
} else { // De lo contrario 
    // Aqui tu codigo para mostrar que esta cerrado
}
```